# Symfony2 service

Tags: php, symfony, service

I have 2 tables in DB (`question` and `answer`). One question has many answers.

I get some `Answers` and depends on `question.type` I prepare results array.

In app without any framework I have `Factory` class which return specific object (`SingleChoiceQuestion`, `OpenQuestion`, `MultipleChoiceQuestion`) depends `question.type` from DB. All `Questions` extends abstract class `Question` which has declared `abstract` method `getResults`. All types have their own business logic to prepare results.

So in this situation when I have created object by factory I'm using method `getResults` and everything works well.

I would like to create it in Symfony and I read documentation. In my opinion I should create services for all my `Question` types.

I have created `AggregatedResultsManager` with method `generate` which returns results array. Depends on `question.type` it calls `getResults` method from specific `service`.

I would like to add, that I can't change DB structure.

**My questions:**

1. Am I creating and using `services` right? If I do it wrong, please help me understanding it and show me the right way.
2. I will have several services like `AggregatedResultsManager` and about 18 Question types.

In each service I will need to create `switch` with 18 choices, how to prevent that?

```
switch ($this->question->getType()) {
    case Question::SINGLE:
        $results = $this->container->get('app.single_choice_question')->getResults($answers);
        break;
    // other types
}
```

I have some idea to create array with types and service names:

```
$services = [
    Question::SINGLE => 'app.single_choice_question',
    Question::MULTIPLE => 'app.multiple_choice_question',
    Question::OPEN => 'app.open_question',
];
```

and then use it in each service like that:

```
$results = $this->container->get($services[$this->question->getType()])->getResults($answers);
```

I think it's the best way to not use switch with 18 choices. But I will need to hardcode service names in array.

**My code:**

services.yml

```
app.question:
    class: AppBundle\Questions\Question
    abstract: true
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']

app.single_choice_question:
    class: AppBundle\Questions\SingleChoice
    parent: app.question

app.agreggated_results_manager:
    class:  AppBundle\Results\AggregatedResultsManager
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@service_container']
```

abstract Question

```
abstract class Question
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    abstract public function getResults($answers);
}
```

SingleChoice

```
class SingleChoice extends Question
{
    public function getResults($answers)
    {
        $results = [];

        // business logic

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Results

```
class AggregatedResultsManager
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var Question
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, ContainerInterface     $container)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        if (!$this->question) {
            throw new \LogicException('Question is not set');
        }

        $answers = $this->em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Answer')
            ->findBy(['question' => $this->question]);

        $results = [];

        if (empty($answers)) {
            return $results;
        }

        switch ($this->question->getType()) {
            case Question::SINGLE:
                $results = $this->container->get('app.single_choice_question')->getResults($answers);
                break;
            // other types
        }

        return $results;
    }


    public function setQuestion(Question $question)
    {
        $this->question = $question;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function questionIdsAction(Question $question)
{
    $resultsManager = $this->get('app.agreggated_results_manager');
    $resultsManager->setQuestion($question);
    $results = $resultsManager->generate();

    return new JsonResponse($results);
}
```

Comment: Having a hard time trying to figure out just what the question is.  Might even be more than one?  If you don't get any useful answer you might consider trying to simplify things a bit.

Comment: @Cerad You right! The only real question I see he's asking, is: `Am I creating and using services right?`

Comment: @Cerad Thanks guys for feedback. I added questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saying that you have 18 QuestionTypes all extending an AbstractQuestion which needs the entity manager to do it's work?  Instead of making 18 services and then using the container I would suggest making a question factory:

```
class QuestionFactory
    public function __construct($entityManager)
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    public function create($questionType)
        switch($questionType) {
            case Question::SINGLE: return new SingleQuestion($this->entityManager);
```

You would then inject the factory into the results manager.

This approach avoids the need to create a bunch of services and of needing to pass around the container.  You still have a switch statement but that is okay.

The only problems that might arise is if some QuestionTypes need additional dependencies.  In which case you might be back to using services.